# How can I fix the @threlte/extras import error sveltekit

Tags: three.js, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to import @threlte/extras into my sveltekit component and I am getting the error "Failed to load url three/examples/jsm/objects/GroundProjectedEnv". I looked in the directory and there is no file there. I am not trying to import that file. I'm not sure why I am getting this error or how to fix it. I have tried importing it two ways but I get the error either way.

```
<script>
    import * as Extra from '@threlte/extras';
    import {GLTF} from '@threlte/extras'
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to [this](https://github.com/threlte/threlte/issues/356) post I was able to figure out how to fix the error. It will be fixed in version 6 when it releases however for now how you fix it is going into your node modules -> three/exapmles/jsm/objects and rename GroundProjectedSkybox.js to GroundProjectedEnv.js  You will also need to open the file and rename the class and export from GroundProjectedSkybox to GroundProjectedEnv.